# Canon TS3450 scanner not working anymore after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: scanner, canon, sane

I can't use anymore my Canon TS3450 scanner with simple-scan or xsane since I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.
Connection to the scanner is fine (Wifi). Scanning with Canon utility scangearmp2 works fine. Scanning from another ubuntu box running 20.04 is fine.

The issue I met is: once simple-scan has detected the scanner and I launch a scan it fails stating (in french, sorry):
Echec de la numérisation
Bac d'alimentation vide.

Which roughly translates to:
scan failed
sheet feeder empty.

But this specific Canon scanner does not have a sheet feeder.

Running simple-scan in debug mode I found this line in the output:
`[+16,43s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1352: sane_start (page=0, pass=0) -> SANE_STATUS_NO_DOCS`

Where from a 20.04 I instead get:
`[+24,89s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1285: sane_start (page=0, pass=0) -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD`

I forgot to mention that I tried the out of the box sane package as well as from this source:
http://ppa.launchpad.net/sane-project/sane-git/ubuntu jammy main

giving me:

ii  libsane:amd64                              1.1.1+git20220801-jammy0                amd64        API library for scanners [transitional package]

ii  libsane-common                             1.1.1+git20220801-jammy0                all

I am running out of ideas... Looks like a 'sane' issue. Help will be very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

My own device is a Canon ImageCLASS MF3010, so I can't give specifics for your device.  However ...

If you did an OS upgrade, then all required Canon libraries should already be installed (but not necessarily functional; more about this later).

If you installed the new OS on an empty partition then made that the boot partition, then you need to re-install the libraries supporting your Canon ... **from Canon**.

In both cases, you will need to perform the "install" step specified in the Canon support package downloaded from Canon.  That will ensure the proper re-compile/linking of libraries with the active libraries installed with the OS.

I've had to do that for my last 3 Ubuntu LTS upgrades.

You might also want to check to see if there is an update to the Canon support package for your device.  I'm in Canada, but in the past, I've had to hunt on the UK site, US site and Taiwan/Japan site to identify the correct package for the latest installed OS.  That is one of the reasons why I always postpone my upgrade to nn.04.1 (not nn.04) until the nn.10 releases are almost out.  That gives the Canon developers time to catch up with the final nn.04 release and fix what may have been broken by last minute Ubuntu patches for the nn.04 release.

You may also want to check:

https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts3450.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)

Comment: HI Eric. Thanks. That was an upgrade, not a fresh install. Following your suggestions I have tried to remove and then reinstall scangearmp2 after a fresh download, but that did not change anything. scangearmp2 still works, but 'simple scan' or xsane doesn't

Comment: The output from `scanimage -L` would be very useful.

Comment: from a 20.04 ubuntu scanimage -L output is `device escl:https://192.168.0.50:443 is a ESCL Canon TS3400 series SSL flatbed scanner
device escl:http://192.168.0.50:80 is a ESCL Canon TS3400 series flatbed scanner`. From a 22.04 ubuntu I get a slightly different output: `device escl:https://192.168.0.50:443 is a Canon TS3400 series platen scanner`

Answer (score 1):

The target OS is Ubuntu 22.04, so we will concentrate on that.

Ubuntu 22.04 provides the **sane-airscan** package by default. Check it is installed: `dpkg -l sane-airscan`.

The worrying thing here is that the `scanimage -L` output does not show a device beginning *airscan*. An *escl* device (which roughly does the same as *airscan*) is shown and scanning should take place with `simple-scan escl:https://192.168.0.50:443"` and `xsane "escl:https://192.168.0.50:443"`. If it does not, it is a bug in *escl*.

I have found *airscan* to be far more reliable than *escl*, so its absence from the `scanimage -L` output needs investigation, especially as the Canon TS3450 appears to be a very recent machine (2020?).

A data point: scangearmp2 is a product from Canon. It **does not** use the SANE framework but contacts the scanner directly. It works because Canon know precisely how the scanner functions.

Finally: the SANE *escl* driver can discover the scanner. Therefore the SANE *airscan* driver should do the same as they both use mDNS.

Why *sane-airscan* was not on the system after an upgrade to 22.04 is a mystery. However, it is there now and it should be possible to get consistent scanning with `simple-scan "airscan:e0:Canon TS3400 series"` or `xsane "airscan:e0:Canon TS3400 series"`. Please say whether scanning takes place with either of these commands.

Should you get this outcome, we can move on from there.

We now have success with the *airscan* driver bur @gfa is a little confused by being presented with a choice of drivers. Understandable.

Open the file **/etc/sane.d/dll.conf** with an editor using sudo and find the line with *escl*. Put a **#** at the beginning of the line; like so: `#escl`. Now simple-scan and xsane will offer only the *airscan* driver. It is all that is needed for reliable scanning.

Comment: HI. sane-airscan was not installed. After installing it now get this output from scanimage:
`device escl:https://192.168.0.50:443' is a Canon TS3400 series platen scanner
device airscan:e0:Canon TS3400 series' is a eSCL Canon TS3400 series ip=192.168.0.50`
I have been able to perform a scan but with some issues. I believe that I made mistakes when choosing between escl or airscan as both were shown.
It looks like it was just a temporary glitch. I'll check again later to see if it is stable now. In any cases it is an improvement, so many thanks for the help.

Comment: Just gave another try and it appears that initially both escl and airscan 'devices' are available. After a scan via airscan I only get to see the airscan device. escl disappears. It might be the reason why I got confused at the first test. Not sure if there is a way not to get initially presented with the escl one, as it might result in picking the wrong one...

Comment: @gfa I have added to my answer. Don't forget to say whether you get scanning with the commands I gave.

Comment: Both commands work. I realize that I did not state clearly earlier that I was successful in scanning using simple-scan on condition that I pick the right device. Using your commands obviously avoid any mistakes while picking. But I have noticed again that scanimage did found initially two devices (escl and airscan) but then found only one once a first scan has been perfomred. Not a big problem, but if there is an easy way to get rid of the escl entry...

Comment: BTW the reason for sane-airscan not to be installed might be because I used before the Ubuntu upgrade an alternative source/repositoty for sane. It might have caused issues for the Ubuntu upgrade process.

Comment: @gfa I have again added to to my answer. You should now have a happy scanning setup :).

Comment: Indeed. It works just fine. Problem solved ! Thanks a lot for your help!